# Django: make an addition inside of a model.objects.filter.update()

Tags: python, django

I have this view that has a form and I want to update a field of a model based on the user input. I cannot find a way to do that. The pytonic way `=+` does not seem to work in this situation.

Here is my view:

```
def orders_on_the_way_edit2(request, Id):
   
    OnOrder2 = get_object_or_404(table_on_order, Id=Id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OnOrderUpdateForm(request.POST, instance = OnOrder2)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            form.save()
            
        quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity_received')
        id = form.cleaned_data.get('Id')
        update2 = table_on_order.objects.filter(Id = Id).update(Quantity_received =+ quantity)
        update = table_on_order.objects.filter(Id = Id).update(StockOnOrder = (StockOnOrder - quantity))
        messages.success(request, "Changed in order status successfully recorded")
        return redirect('OnOrder2')
    else:
        form = OnOrderUpdateForm(initial = {
            'Id' : OnOrder2.Id,
            'StockOnOrder' : OnOrder2.StockOnOrder,
            'Quantity_received' : OnOrder2.Quantity_received,
            'OrderCompleted' : OnOrder2.OrderCompleted}, instance =OnOrder2)
                                 
        return render(request, 'OnOrder2edit.html', {'form' : form})
```

the lines:

```
update2 = table_on_order.objects.filter(Id = Id).update(Quantity_received =+ quantity)
        update = table_on_order.objects.filter(Id = Id).update(StockOnOrder = (StockOnOrder - quantity))
```

are causing the issue, `update1` replaces the existing value by `quantity` and `update2` gives me an error.

Any clue on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The pytonic way `+=` does not seem to work in this situation.

**No**, since this is after all a function call. Django can not alter Python's language. But it has some objects, etc. to make updates to fields.

As explained in the documentation on [**`.update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update), you can make use of an [**`F`**-object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to refer to a field, so:

```
from django.db.models import F

update2 = table_on_order.objects.filter(Id=Id).update(
    Quantity_received=F('Quantity_received') + quantity
)
table_on_order.objects.filter(Id=Id).update(
    StockOnOrder=F('StockOnOrder') - quantity
)
```

You can combine the two queries here and thus update both fields with:

```
from django.db.models import F

update = table_on_order.objects.filter(Id=Id).update(
    Quantity_received=F('Quantity_received') + quantity,
    StockOnOrder=F('StockOnOrder') - quantity
)
```

by combining the two, we thus make one roundtrip to the database instead of two.